# How to perfectly align the logo and navbar horizontally?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to align the logo on the left side and the nav links on the right side horizontally.

Mainly, I used `display: flex` on `.nav-wrapper` and used `align-items: center`. However, there still seems to be a bit of misalignment between the logo and the nav link elements which I cannot seem to figure out how to properly correct. Would really appreciate some help on this!

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-left: 30px;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.right-menu {
    display: flex;
    padding-right: 12px;
}

.right-menu .right-menu-items {
    display: flex;
}

.right-menu .right-menu-items li a {
    padding: 0 12px;
}

.logo {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}

.main-wrapper {
    background-image: url("/assets/lucrezia-carnelos-gvc7MK4gnDk-unsplash.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.main-wrapper .welcome-note {
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>italki: Learn a language online</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <header class="nav-wrapper">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="./assets/white_logo.svg" alt="italki logo" class="logo" />
            </a>
            <nav class="right-menu">
                <ul class="right-menu-items">
                    <li><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Become a Teacher</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="main-wrapper">
            <div class="welcome-note">
                <h1>Become fluent in <br />any language</h1>
                <p
                    >Choose from over 10,000 teachers for 1-on-1 lessons based on your
                    goals and interests</p
                >
                <input type="text" placeholder="Choose a language" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the current output?

Comment: Hello! Here they are [dropboxlink](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w7vi3ryq5ti3kom/img-1.PNG?dl=0) and [dropboxlink](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kc2wnouc54lcd5l/img-2.PNG?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created demo, Here Link: https://jsfiddle.net/590nartL/

[image]

Infact it really horizontally center, red border prove that.

Of couse, maybe you think font in red border box not vertical middle, you can add style as below:

```css
.right-menu {
  margin-top: -2px;
}
```

Any negative margin value as you want.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because there is an unnecessary space between the `<img>` tag and the parent `<a>` tag.

The `<img>` is an inline element so this happened.

To remove the space, make `<img>` tag as `block` element as follows or implement vertical-align.

```
.logo {
  display: block;

  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

or make parent `<a>` as flex style

```
a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```